# What is $\int_\Omega 1_{X^{-1}(A)}dP=\int_\mathbb R 1_AdP_X$ intuitively and why does it make sense?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

[image: Equality of integrals over Omega and over reals with respective measures]

What I don't get is:

1. why does this make sense, we are integrating in two different measured spaces
2. is this equality important? Why do we need it?

**EDIT :** I'm talking about the integral equality and not the indicator function.

**P.S:** I'm not looking for the proof, just the intuition.

Comment: Sorry, wich equality?

Comment: @TitoEliatron Sorry, I wasn't clear enough, I'm talking about the integral equality.

Comment: I think you should give more details and background about your question, notation,...

Comment: This is nothing but the definition of the measure $\mathbb P_X$.  Thus it makes as much sense as any other definition
in Math, such as
  $$
  f'(x) = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}.
  $$
  In particular there is no point in trying to prove it!  A better question would be why is it useful to define this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the equality is very important. A priori it makes sense since, being integrals, the left- and the right-hand side are both real numbers. For an explanation why this holds as you wrote it down, recall that the integral over an indicator function is (by definition) the measure of the underlying set i.e. the left-hand side

$$ \int_{\Omega} 1_{X^{-1}(A)}(\omega) d\mathbb{P}(\omega) = \mathbb{P}(X^{-1}(A)) $$

and on the right-hand side:

$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}} 1_{A}(x) d\mathbb{P}_X(x) = \mathbb{P}_X(A) $$

The reason for why this is true is precisely the definition of the probability measure $\mathbb{P}_X$, the distribution of $X$.

So in the case of an indicator function it is clear that this holds, but it also holds for arbitrary (integrable) functions i.e. for any integrable function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ it is true that

$$ \int_{\Omega} f(X(\omega)) d\mathbb{P}(\omega) =  \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) d\mathbb{P}_X(x)$$

and that's the important part.

Usually one has no (or only little) information about $\mathbb{P}$, let alone $\Omega$) but there is information about $\mathbb{P}_X$. In many cases this measure even has a density. So what we are doing is transformaing some abstract,inaccesible into a very concrete, computable one.

Example: Consider a normally distributed random variable $X$ with mean $\mu = 400$ and standard deviation $\sigma = 100$, and we want to compute the percentage that $X$ is below $300$. Now that would mean to evaluate the integral

$$ \int_{\Omega} 1_{\{\omega \in \Omega: X(\omega) < 300\}} (\omega) d \mathbb{P}(\omega)$$

How can one possibly evaluate that? Apply the transformation above to obtain

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{300} d\mathbb{P}_X(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{300} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi 100^2}} \exp(- \frac{(x-300)^2}{2 \cdot 100^2}) dx $$

where the last integrand is just the density of the normal distribution.

Answer (score 2):

$$(*)\int_\Omega1_{X^{-1}(A)}dP=\int_{\mathbb{R}}1_AdP_X$$
Why do we need it? Well, exactly because thanks to this, we can integrate in two different spaces. As to why it makes sense, there are whole books/courses carefully developing this theory, so all I can do here is short sketch of an idea. Basic idea is, that measurable function induces [pushforward measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure) on the codomain.

Lets fix any [probability space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_space#Definition) $(\Omega, \Sigma, P)$ and real line with Lebesgue measure over borel sets $(\mathbb R, \mathcal B (\mathbb R), \mathcal L)$, and measurable function $X:\Omega\to\mathbb R$. Then the *distribution $P_X$ of $X$* is defined by
$$(**)P_X:\mathcal B (\mathbb R)\ni A\mapsto P(X^{-1}(A))\in [0,1]$$

Such defined $P_X$ is probabilistic measure on $\mathbb R$. In plain english $P(X^{-1}(A))$ means "probability, that outcome of $X$ has value in $A$". Standard abuse of notation is to use $P(X\in A)$ in place of $P(X^{-1}(A))$.

Because every probability space is measure space, we can develop Lebesgue integral in it. Long story short, characteristic function of a set is [first step](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_integration#Constructing_the_integral) in the construction of the integral. Knowing the definition of integral over characteristic function:
$$(***.1)\ \int_\Omega1_{X^{-1}(A)}dP=P(X^{-1}(A))$$
$$(***.2)\ \int_{\mathbb{R}}1_AdP_X=P_X(A)$$

then the equation in your question (*) is indeed immediate consequence of the definitions of integral (***) and distribution (**), and may look confusingly trivial. Here is at last a turning point which leads from this abstract considerations of measure theory to actual probability theory: what are properties of the distribution $P_X$? Without any further informations about $P_X$ we can look at [cumulative distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function):
$$CDF_X:\mathbb R\ni t\mapsto P_X((-\inf,t])\in [0,1]$$

If $P_X$ is [absolutely continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity#Absolute_continuity_of_measures) with respect to $\mathcal L$ - standard measure in $\mathbb R$, then by [Radon-Nikodym theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem#Radon.E2.80.93Nikodym_derivative) there exists function $f_{X}:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$, such that:
$$\int_{\mathbb R}1_AdP_X=\int_{\mathbb R}1_Af_Xd\mathcal L$$
$f_X$ is called probability density function. Now if we can find $f_X$, we can also do all sort of rudimentary calculus. In particular:
$$\int_\mathbb R ^t f_Xd\mathcal L=CDF_X(t)$$

On the other hand, if $P_X$ is not absolutely continuous, we can examine it more closely by [Lebesuge's decomposition theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%27s_decomposition_theorem). But among others, there is well known [discrete measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_measure). If probability is discrete, all integral symbols can be simplified to sums in finite case, and series in countably infinite. Such expressions are meaningful, because there are at most countably infinite real values $t$ such, that $P_X(t)\neq 0$. For example cumulative distribution function takes form:
$$CDF_X(t)=\int_\mathbb R 1_{(-\infty, t]}dP_X=\sum_{u\in(-\infty, t]}P_X(u)$$
and such discrete measure $P_X$ is called probability mass function.